# How to change message vibration type on s2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sms, vibration

How can I change message vibration type on galaxy s2? After jb update it vibrates the same (basic call). In settings I changed for example into heartbeat, but it doesnt vibrate this type when I receiving message. And in message settings is only enable or disablle vibration... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On my Galaxy S III at least, you can only change settings for call vibration. However, I believe if you use a 3rd party SMS program (eg: Handcent SMS, or any other (mostly free) apps on the market), then you are usually able to set custom vibration themes.